# Angular 2 - How to set animations on a Directive?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a `Directive` I can put on elements that checks the current scroll position of the element in question.

Looks like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[my-scroll-animation]'
})
```

Whenever the position satifies a certain treshold, I want the element to appear on screen using an animation. I know that for a `Component` I can attach an `animations` property along with some settings in the `host` property to activate the animation.

I would like something like this:

```
import { myScrollAnimation } from './animations';

@Directive({
    selector: '[my-scroll-animation]'
    animations: [myScrollAnimation] // <- not possible?
})
```

How can I achieve this in a Directive?

Using: Angular `4.0.0-rc.4`

Comment: Yes, directives don't have `animations`, likely because there may be multiple directives per element and animations have to be stacked somehow. Still wonder what's the neatest way to do this.

Comment: If you simply want reusable animations for your components, you could create an `animation.ts` file, and reference it as an animation in your component.

Comment: The point is not about sharing animations, but rather triggering them from within a Directive.

Comment: I believe angular uses css animations (transition, transform, etc).
Since directives do not have templates and styles, the closest thing you can achieve is probably altering the class or attribute inside the directive, while having the animation configurations in your parent component.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Angular 4.2 brought in a lot of animation improvements. One of them is `AnimationBuilder`, which allows for programmatic animation construction.

You just need to inject `AnimationBuilder` in your directive, and you can turn any `AnimationMetadata` into working animation.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[zetFadeInOut]',
})
export class FadeInOutDirective {

  @Input()
  set show(show: boolean) {
    const metadata = show ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut();

    const factory = this.builder.build(metadata);
    const player = factory.create(this.el.nativeElement);

    player.play();
  }

  constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder, private el: ElementRef) {}

  private fadeIn(): AnimationMetadata[] {
    return [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      animate('400ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1 })),
    ];
  }

  private fadeOut(): AnimationMetadata[] {
    return [
      style({ opacity: '*' }),
      animate('400ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    ];
  }
}
```

- [Example repository](https://github.com/zetsnotdead/ng-programmatic-animation-construction)
- [A New Wave of Animation Features in Angular 4.2+](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html)

Comment: The second link you posted is a new way to made a directive?

Comment: man you solved one of my big problems!! I have asked tones of questions about dynamic animations on angular with almost NO ANSWER.

Comment: "A New Wave" Link is broken, [this might be](https://www.concettolabs.com/blog/need-to-know-new-angularjs-4-2/) a similar alternative on 4.2+ News...

Comment: Is it work with `ng-if`? I've tried with `ngAfterInit` and it works for `fadeIn`, not for `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 12):

I used a bit of a workaround based on [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9947#issuecomment-305672186) response to the issue mentioned in benshabatnoam's answer.

Directives are actually just components without templates. You can create a component that acts identical to a directive by using a attribute selector ( eg: `[selector]`) and making the template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`.

As a result, you can create a 'foux-directive' component like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[fadeInAnimation]',
    animations: [
        trigger('fadeIn', [
             transition(':enter', [
                 style({opacity:'0'}),
                 animate(200, style({opacity:'1'}))
             ])
        ])
    ], 
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class FadeInDirective {
    @HostBinding('@fadeIn') trigger = '';
}
```

and use it like you would use any directive:

```
<div fadeInAnimation> something I want to animate </div>
```

Comment: Your solution work great. Thank you. ut I cant understand why you didnt work with Derective decorator ?instead of Compononet

Comment: Directives do not support animations, so the directive decorator would not work

Comment: I tried and it works also for `fadeOut` :)

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in your question's comment section.

You can have the animation configuration in your parent component.
Then the directive just adds a class on its host when it satisfies the threshold.

In your directive, you can have something like:

```
@Input() classThatTriggersAnimation = "do-animation";
@HostBinding('[@nameOfAnimation]') animationTrigger = ""; 

// when logic is true
this.animationTrigger = this.classThatTriggersAnimation;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful. But in my case, I'm developing a plugin, meaning I don't have control over the parent `Component` that's hosting the template.

Comment: If that's the case, you will have to create a component instead of a directive, which can contain dynamic content.

You could look into bootstrap code on how they create modals, where you can pass "content".

Comment: Great answer. Just I guess it should be `@HostBinding('@nameOfAnimation')`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9947) (as for today - 28/08/17) in Angular's git repository. Please vote up this issue in order to put pressure on the developers to release this faster.

Answer (score 2):

**Here we go. Good for tiny animations.**

I am directly using [AnimationPlayer + AnimationBuilder](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationPlayer#reset) => No need to artificially toggle a state forth + back to trigger the animation. Inspired by and further reduced from [this snippet](https://github.com/zetsnotdead/ng-programmatic-animation-construction/blob/911e95e1a1d236bfe6af4e8441e5cb47f10de675/src/app/fade-in-out.directive.ts).

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
    AnimationPlayer,
    AnimationBuilder
} from '@angular/animations';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickAnimation]',
})
export class ClickAnimationDirective {
    private player: AnimationPlayer;

    @Input() clickAnimation: any;

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick() {
        // sanitize just in case
        if (this.player) { this.player.destroy(); }

        const factory = this.builder.build(this.clickAnimation);
        const player = factory.create(this.el.nativeElement);

        // ensure back-to-original
        player.onDone(() => { player.reset(); });
        player.play();
    }

    constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder, private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

In your template:

```
<app-button
    [clickAnimation]="trafficLight"
    ...
```

In your component class:

```
public trafficLight: AnimationMetadata[] = [
    style({ borderColor: 'red' }),
    animate('400ms ease-in', style({ borderColor: 'yellow' })),
    animate('400ms ease-in', style({ borderColor: 'cyan' })),
    //alternative way to ensure back to original
    // animate('400ms ease-in', style({ borderColor: '*' })), 
];
```

Comment: This was great. It fulfills the need of single responsibility and doesn't make component file dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a late response, but I was able to add animations by using the ElementRef for the element the directive is being applied on, and then using the  inbuilt nativeelement's animate function:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[grayscaleFade]'
})
export class GrayscaleFadeDirective {

  constructor(private rawElement: ElementRef) {
    this.rawElement.nativeElement.style.filter = "grayscale(1)"
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.rawElement.nativeElement.animate([
        {filter: "grayscale(1)"},
        {filter: "grayscale(0)"},
      ],
      {
        duration: 300,
        delay: 0,
        fill: "both",
        easing :'ease-in-out',
        trigger: 'enter'
      }).play();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseExit() {
    this.rawElement.nativeElement.animate([
        {filter: "grayscale(0)"},
        {filter: "grayscale(1)"},
      ],
      {
        duration: 300,
        delay: 0,
        fill: "both",
        easing :'ease-in-out',
        trigger: 'enter'
      }).play();
  }
}
```

It is important to mention that without the call to `.play()`, this won't run. I spent a while trying to figure that out.

It seems that animate is not an angular function, rather part of the MDN specifications:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate