# How can a directive play an animation on some parent element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-directive

[[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmt4gj?file=src%2Fng-peek-behind%2Fng-peek-behind.directive.ts)]
I have a directive that I would like to animate an arbitrary element in the DOM. I feel like I am doing something wrong here -

```
// this returns the right element
this.panelParentElement = this.element.closest('.cdk-overlay-pane') as HTMLElement;

const animation = this.panelParentElement.animate([{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }]);
animation.play();
```

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49440416/4327976) from a similar thread (replace directive with a template-less component), but to no avail.

The accepted answer from [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878197/angular-2-how-to-set-animations-on-a-directive) works, but I want to understand why my method doesn't since I am querying an arbitrary DOM element and trying to apply an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using totally different API, which does different things - hence why it's not working.

You are using a native html [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate), while the example is using the [angular's animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations).

In your example you defined one keyframe and no duration. As per specs, this means the animation won't play, since there is no delay between different frames.